# Sql where t.date attribute is less than current year

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

In my Rails 3 app, I'm attempting to do a find of current students by their school's name and their graduation date in relation to the current year. I can do a successful find for users without a graduation date (see below), but I want to search users who have a graduation date attribute less than - or greater than - the current year. FYI, I'm using PostgreSQL.

The fields I'm using are set up as follows:

```
t.string :high_school
t.date :hs_grad_year
```

Here's the find I have working currently:

```
<%= pluralize(Profile.where(:high_school => "#{@highschool.name}").where("hs_grad_year IS NOT NULL").count, "person") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple issues with your code (getting records from your database should be done in the controller, not in the view, and you're using high school names as foreign keys instead of an `id` field, for example), but to answer your question:

```
Profile.where %'
    high_school = ? AND
    EXTRACT(year FROM hs_grad_year) < EXTRACT(year FROM current_date)
  ',
  @highschool.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to keep it in the controller. I'll make sure that's where it remains.

Answer (score 1):

You want a `.where("hs_grad_year < extract(year from current_date)")` in there.

In Postgres, `current_date` is the current date (`yyyy-mm-dd`), and the `extract` function pulls just one part of that date out of it. You can read more about date and time functions in Postgres [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: Thanks for explaining extract so well. That helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
Profile.
  where(:high_school => @highschool.name).
  where("hs_grad_year < ? OR hs_grad_year > ?", Date.today.year, Date.today.year)
```